# ADO .NET blocking despite async calls

Tags: mysql, wpf, ado.net

I have a WPF application where I am doing some database operations when a user clicks on a button. The button click is bound to a command using the RelayCommand from GalaSoft's MVVM Light.

MySQL is giving me timeouts because of the large amount of data, but the real problem is another. I am doing everything asynchronously, and yet, the application is blocking until the timeout elapses.

[image]

I always expect the UI to remain responsive while an asynchronous operation is running. For example if I do a GET request using `HttpClient`, no matter how long it takes to come back with a response, I can still use the UI.

I am using the Pomelo data provider for MySQL (Pomelo.Data.MySql).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Pomelo implementation of `ExecuteReaderAsync()` [uses the blocking implementation and wraps it in a `TaskCompletionSource`](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.Data.MySql/blob/aaf215852d594d09cf6518e50392b596b46a9f18/src/Pomelo.Data.MySql/MySqlHelper.cs#L727).

Comment: As I remember, even "official" mysql provider is doing that. You can try this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/